# What will I see if I look through a diffraction grating?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, diffraction

The problem comes from a past exam, which is apparently causing a lot of
confusion between my classmates and teacher.  I'll put a slightly paraphrased
version here:

> Light of a single wavelength from a distant point source falls approximately
> normally onto a diffraction grating positioned with its lines vertical.  A
> student looks at the grating with an eye from a position behind it, and if
> he/she goes near enough to the grating, what would be seen?
>
> - A: a central point source with a series of point source images on either
>   side
> - B: a central vertical line with a series of spectra on either side
> - C: a series of fine vertical lines
> - D: a single point source

The official answer is C, which makes perfect sense if the question asks what
the image projected on a screen behind the grating will be.  However it asks
for the image seen by an eye.  Suppose that the eye is large enough, so that
more than one line of maxima enters it, then it seems that the eye should see
multiple images, which leads to choices A and C.  But given that the lines are
vertical on the grating, I think there should be no diffraction in the vertical
direction, which means vertically the image is unchanged, and since it is a
point source, vertically the image(s) seen by the eye should be a point.
Therefore, A should be chosen.

Then what would actually be the image seen, and why?

Comment: Can you not just look through one of your teachers' diffraction gratings at a lightbulb and unambiguously get the right answer?

Comment: Thanks! We had actually tested with laser beam and camera, and the photos turned out to be with distinct points instead of vertical lines. But the fact that it was too dangerous to look at the laser directly made it not so satisfying, and we didn't tried the experiment with LED in a dark room. So it seems pretty clear that we would be seeing points instead of lines, if the source is monochromatic.

Comment: You are correct. Glad to be of a little help, but you already knew the expected result!

Comment: Perhaps of interest: with a transmission grating, camera and inexpensive software, people get beautiful spectra of stars: https://www.rspec-astro.com/. I bought the grating and software, but have not had time to play with it.